# How to set visual studio 2008 load files from Release folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have two projects, one project loads files from the project folder, one project loads files from the project/release folder.

How to change both projects to load files from the project/release folder?

Note: its loading all the DLL files etc. from the project folder, instead of project/release when i compile the project and it launches my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean when debugging?

```
project properties->configuration properties->debugging->working directory
```

you can set it to *$(TargetDir)*

Comment: That did the trick. How its possible that the other project doesnt have this set to anything, but still works the same way as `$(TargetDir)` ? Thats why i couldnt find the setting when i compared the projects... -_-

Comment: I mean the project settings both were identical, i couldnt see `$(TargetDir)` on the other project at all... still it worked like it had that setting. (I cant accept answers too fast here, its time limited. 1 minute left...)

Comment: are both of them same project types (c++, .Net, etc.)?